# Why XMLMessageProducer is closed when called by multiple threads?

Tags: solace

I encapsulated JCSMP API in a class and provide methods for other classes to send and consume messages.

I have the following method:

```
    public void send(byte[] data, String queueName) throws JCSMPException {
    // Acquire a message producer
    if (producer == null) { //producer is an instance of XMLMessageProducer
        producer = session.getMessageProducer(new PublishCallback());
    }

    Queue queue = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createQueue(queueName);
    BytesMessage msg = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createMessage(BytesMessage.class);
    msg.setData(data);
    msg.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

    logger.info("Sending to \"{}\"", queueName);

    producer.send(msg, queue);
}
```

When I have multiple threads calling this method, once in a while, I notice the following exception:

com.solacesystems.jcsmp.ClosedFacilityException: Tried to perform operation on a closed XML message producer

I wonder whether the producer is closed after each call to send().  How should I make this method thread-safe? 
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you get around this problem? or still get it?

Answer (score 0):

`XMLMessageProducer` does not close itself after each call to send.

The first step here is to investigate why your `XMLMessageProducer` is closed. The easiest option to do this is to enable the Solace API logging to INFO (or even DEBUG), and edit your question to include the Solace API logs prior to the first `ClosedFacilityException`.

One possible reason is that your application has disconnected, but was not able to automatically reconnect to the Solace appliance/VMR.